# JPA Entity Relationship for referencing the value but not updating the referenced entity

Tags: jpa, mapping

There are two entities, 
1. Status (two columns: statusId status) 
      e.g. values: 1  ACTIVE, 2 INACTIVE, etc.) 
2. Coupon (three columns: couponId title statusId) 
      e.g. values: 10 Oranges 1, 20 Apples 2, etc.)

Trying to figure out what relationship to be used and how. I tried OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne, ManyToMany etc. but every time Status entity gets a new row added 
e.g. 21 ACTIVE, 22 ACTIVE, 23 Active, etc.

The Coupon entity should get a new row every time a new coupon is saved and use the primary key of status in status id field but the status entity should be get a new row added.

```
Yes, Many coupons can share the same status.
The following code produces the following results

Before execution

Status Table
StatusId    STATUS
1           ACTIVE
2           INACTIVE

Coupon Table
CouponId    Title   STATUS
<no rows at present>


After execution

Status Table
StatusId    STATUS
1           ACTIVE
2           INACTIVE
3           ACTIVE  (This row should not get inserted)

Coupon Table
CouponId        Title   StatusId
10          Apples  3     (StatusId should be 1 instead of 3)




JSON Request: 

{
  "title": "Apples",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
}

Code:

@Autowired
CouponRespository couponRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/coupon", method = RequestMethod.POST)
void createCoupon(@RequestBody Coupon coupon) {
        couponRepository.save(coupon);
}

public interface CouponRespository extends JpaRepository<Coupon, Long> {

}

@Entity 
public class Status implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "STATUS_STATUSID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "STATUS_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STATUS_STATUSID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
    private long statusId;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private String status;   
}


@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,    property = "couponId")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "statusId" }) 
public class Coupon implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COUPON_COUPONID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "COUPON_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "COUPON_COUPONID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "COUPON_ID")
    private long couponId;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
    private Long statusId;

    // Need help here how to set this up properly
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(name = "STATUS_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Status status;

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, can many coupons share the same status, or not? If yes, then it's a ManyToOne, otherwise it's a OneToOne. Post the code you used to create and save a coupon, tell what you expect it to do and what it does instead.

Comment: @JBNizet Added the code along with what is expected and what is getting updated in database

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how Jackson can possibly create a Coupon instance containing a Status instance from the JSON in your question, and even less how a new row could appear in the database, since the status field of COupon is not insertable, but anyway, suppose it does the equivalent of the following:

```
Coupon coupon = new Coupon();
coupon.setTitle("Apples");
Status status = new Status("ACTIVE");
coupon.setStatus(status);
```

You're asking to save that coupon to JPA. And you told JPA to cascade the persist operation to the status contained in the coupon. The status doesn't have any ID. So what can JPA do other than create a new one? How could it guess that what you actually want is to associate the new coupon with the already existing status identified by the ID 1? It can't. It does what you're telling it to do.

So, what should you do?

First, remove the statusId field from Coupon. This is the ID of the status, and you have the status in the coupon, so this information is redundant.

Second, you want the coupon to be associated to an **existing** status. So, get a reference to this existing status, and set it in the coupon before saving the coupon:

```
// this should execute a query that retrieves the Status entity 
// that has the "ACTIVE" status
Status status = statusRepository.findStatusByStatus("ACTIVE");

coupon.setStatus(status);
couponRepository.save(coupon);
```

Third: since you don't want two status in database with the same status, add a unique constraint to the table.

Fourth: since you don't want to save or modify or delete the status when you save or modify or delete a coupon that references this status, remove `cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }`.

Fifth: since you want the changes to coupon.status to be persistent, remove `insertable = false, updatable = false`.

Sixth: since what your receive as JSON in your controller doesn't have the structure of a Coupon, and is not a Coupon instance but a title and a status text that allow you to find the Status with that text and create a Coupon instance, create a class CouponCommandDTO, which has the same structure as your JSON, and make that the type of the parameter of your controller. Then transform this DTO to an actual Coupon using the code shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Apart from the basic question, there were some additional queries which I were not clear to me, but your elaborate explanation, answered all my questions.  I tried the solution you mentioned and it worked. The only thing I didn't do was instead of creating CouponCommandDTO, I made the status_id as transient and used that value to get the status object. Thanks again. Not only it solved the problem but it cleared lot of other doubts which was troubling me.